# Can't move apps to SD Card on Huawei

Tags: storage, huawei, emui

I own a P9 Lite(EMUI 5.0, Android 7.0) and when I'm trying to move an app to my SD Card there is no option, but on someone's P8 Lite with Android 6.0 this option is available, how can I fix this thing and move apps on the SD Card + Data

Answer (score 5):

According to Huawei support, starting with EMUI 5.0 (Android 7.0 Nougat), moving apps to SD Card is no longer supported. Period. Really bad decision if you ask me.

Updated 3/18/2018:
Posed the question again on https://www.facebook.com/usahonor in the 'Flagship' question box and got the answer was that it is as of EMUI 4.1 that apps on SD card are no longer supported. Worse than I initially thought!

Huawei/Honor shooting themselves in the foot it seems...

Comment: Updated comments below

Comment: Source IS (Huawei support) in original post! Update post shows link: https://www.facebook.com/usahonor

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method proposed by pruther69 [here](https://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/Other-OS-Unlocking/Huawei-P9-Lite-Transferring-app-data-to-SD-Card/td-p/2554357) and this method  **should allow app data to be saved to the SD Card**:

1. On your Huawei device navigate to Settings ➡ Apps ➡ Advanced (bottom of screen) ➡ App Permissions ➡ Storage
2. Select respective application from list (this should then allow data for that app to be saved to the SD Card)

**To transfer data from internal memory to SD card:**

- Go to Tools ➡ Files ➡ Local (top right)  ➡ Internal storage and/or SD Card.
- Options should now be available to navigate and move files from one to the other.

Credits

- [Huawei P9 Lite - Transferring app data to SD Card](https://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/Other-OS-Unlocking/Huawei-P9-Lite-Transferring-app-data-to-SD-Card/td-p/2554357)

Comment: Yes I just've seen the post, i'll do this asap and let you know.

Comment: This option is missing on my sister's Huawei P9 Lite running Android 7.0 and the other answer says Huawei says it's not supported. Please don't post answers you haven't verified.